# ACES tonemapping confusion

Tags: color, hdr

In different sources I see ACES tonemapping, but I see one of two possible sets of formulas:

1. https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XsGfWV this one
2. https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tdffDl or this

I compared them and the first one looks better, it can transform very bright monochromatic light to white.

But the question is: why do they both are called ACES and what is the "true" ACES? It seems like number 2 is used alot though number 1 looks better.